# saving the state of radiobuttons

Tags: android

Hi I'm trying to create an app for Android and in order to develop it i need to navigate through different pages where each page has only one question and 4 answers(a,b,c,d). For this task I have defined 4 radiobuttons for each question. What I want to obtain is that if any radiobutton is checked , the other radiobuttons are unchecked (radiobuttons checked false) . And i want that when the user goes thorugh differentes pages the value can be retrieved. I have tried this code , however it worked fine with selecting one answer and uncheck the others , but it didnt work for saving the state of the radiobuttons even though i used shared preferences .

public class Page1 extends Activity {

```
RadioButton r1a , r1b , r1c , r1d ;
Button b1n ; // this is a next-button that will navigate to page2



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);

                SharedPreferences pref ;

    r1a = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Q1a);
    r1b = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Q1b); 
    r1c = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Q1c);
    r1d = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Q1d);
    b1n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B1n);
    pref = getSharedPreferences("Answers", 0); 
      final Editor editor = pref.edit();


    r1a.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            if (r1a.isChecked()){
            r1b.setChecked(false);  
            r1c.setChecked(false);
            r1d.setChecked(false);
            }

            }

    });


    r1b.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

            if (r1b.isChecked()){
            r1a.setChecked(false);  
            r1c.setChecked(false);
            r1d.setChecked(false);
            }

        }

    });


    r1c.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {

            if (r1c.isChecked()){
            r1a.setChecked(false);  
            r1b.setChecked(false);
            r1d.setChecked(false);
             }
            }



    });


    r1d.setOnCheckedChangeListener (new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {


                if (r1d.isChecked()){

            r1c.setChecked(false);  
            r1a.setChecked(false);
            r1b.setChecked(false);
        }

    }

        });

        // i use this to save the state , but it fails :(

        editor.putBoolean("questionA", r1a.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("questionB", r1b.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("questionC", r1c.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("questionD", r1d.isChecked());


        editor.commit();


}


    public void move12(View view) {  // instantiated when b1n is clicked

        Intent intent = new Intent(this , P2.class) ;
        startActivity (intent) ;
    }

}
```

i have two questions here :

- is this code ok ? or is there a better idea for handling the checked buttons ?
- the shared preference does not work , anytime i return to page1 all the radiobuttons are unchecked and the state fail to be saved. what is the cause of the problem ?and how can it be resolved ? any ibeads please .

Answer (score 0):

Your code for saving state is ok. Your radioButtons are unchecked because nowhere in Page1 you actually read from SharedPreferences and set their state. You could add this in onCreate():

```
r1a.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("questionA", false));
r1b.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("questionB", false));
r1c.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("questionC", false));
r1d.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("questionD", false));
```

First though, check if preference file is present and if states of each buttons have been saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of truncate your `onCheckChangedListeners` to just one and then have a switch that checks to see which `RadioButton` was clicked, but the way you did it is fine.

As per saving the data, it doesn't look like you're attempting to read the data that you saved. First of all, you should put all of your data saving inside the `move12` method. Secondly, try adding something like this to your `onCreate`:

```
bool aChecked = prefs.getBoolean("questionA",false);
if(aChecked)
    r1a.setChecked(true);
```

Do that for all four.